# Can I find the Windows Version using tideSDK?

Tags: tidesdk

`Ti.getPlatform()` this method gives me the platform name, eg: osx or win32

In my case,
I want to show the current version of windows .How can I get the Windows Version using tideSDK?

eg: Win7 or Win8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attempting to do this myself, I've concluded: *yes and no*. What you can do is use `Ti.Platform.getVersion()`, which will return something like:

```
6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

What this number indicates is a Windows NT version and build number (`Windows NT` is returned universailly for `Ti.Platform.getName()`, as [it's the basic version of Windows used since Windows 3.1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT)). This data can then be cross-referenced by your application to [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT#Releases) to determine which version is being run.

For the above-returned information, `6.1` is enough to tell you that my machine is running Windows 7. A Windows 8 machine will use `6.2`, while a computer running the recently-released Windows 8.1 update will report `6.3`.

So *no*, as far as I can tell, there is no function that will spit out `Windows 7` or `Windows 8`: but *yes*, it is possible, with a little code, to determine the version yourself.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the answer. I have used the code that we normally do it for browsers, at the end tideSDK uses webkit.

Comment: I have posted the helper that I used as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have used following helper on tideSDK to get the OSNAME out, as I needed both windows and MAC Names.

```
   function findOSVersion(){
      var OSName = "Unknown";
      if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.2") != -1) OSName="WIN8";
      if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.1") != -1) OSName="WIN7";
      if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 6.0") != -1) OSName="Windows Vista";
      if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 5.1") != -1) OSName="WinXP";
      if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows NT 5.0") != -1) OSName="Windows 2000";
      if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MAC";
      if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
      if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
      return OSName
    }
```